# how to check if items in a list can be found as an item in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, append

My question is I want to check if the **items** in this list

```
input_list = ['Calcium','Gold','Lithium','Boron','Carbon']`
```

can be found in this list

```
 elements =  ['Hydrogen','Helium','Lithium','Beryllium','Boron','Carbon','Nitrogen',
              'Oxygen','Fluorine','Neon','Sodium', 'Magnesium','Aluminum','Silicon',
              'Phosphorus','Sulfur','Chlorine','Argon', 'Potassium', 'Calcium']
```

if so and, an item in the **input_list** is found in the **elements list** 
then it should append that item in a different list named **correct_response = []** else then it should append it to another list **incorrect_response = []**

Below is my code for the above question.
Having already imported the file and using **readline()** method to get the string on line at a time.

```
elements1_file = open('elements1_20.txt','r')
counter = 0
while elements_text:
      for ele in elements_text:
          if ele.lower() in input_list[counter]:
             correct_response.append(input_list[counter])
          else:
               incorrect_response.append(input_list[counter])
      counter += 1
elements_text = elements1_file.readline().strip()
```

Now the error I get is list out of index, so I want to know how I can append the correct items in the list by comparing them to the **elements list**

Answer (score 1):

[sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set-types-set-frozenset) are far better suited to deal with this:

```
input_set = set( ['Calcium','Gold','Lithium','Boron','Carbon'] )

elements =  set(['Hydrogen','Helium','Lithium','Beryllium','Boron','Carbon','Nitrogen',
                 'Oxygen','Fluorine','Neon','Sodium', 'Magnesium','Aluminum','Silicon',
                 'Phosphorus','Sulfur','Chlorine','Argon', 'Potassium', 'Calcium'])

correct = list(input_set & elements) 
incorrect = list(input_set - elements)

print(correct)
print(incorrect)
```

Output:

```
['Boron', 'Lithium', 'Calcium', 'Carbon']
['Gold']
```

Intersection: [set.intersection (or &)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.intersection) aka: which elements are in both sets?

Difference: [set.difference (or -)](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#frozenset.difference) aka: what elements are only in the first set?

Answer (score 0):

a simple for loop O(n) to complete the loop up

```
correct_response=list()
incorrect_response=list()

for i in input_list:
  if i in elements:
   correct.append(i)
  else:
   incorrect.append(i)
```